# how to show particular selected person contact form Address Book Ui Iphone?

Tags: iphone, addressbook, abpeoplepickerview

I am implementing address book Ui in my application. And I am getting some problem.

I have a record id and i want to show details of that contact form address book UI frame work.

For that I have used this code:-

> ```
>         ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
>         picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
>         ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate( ); 
>         NSNumber *recordId = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[record_str integerValue]];
>         ABRecordRef person = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook,recordId.integerValue);
>         [self peoplePickerNavigationController:picker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:person];
>         [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
>         [picker release];   
> - (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person{
> return YES;}
> ```

When I run the code then it show all contact list while I have display only given record.

How can I show the address of the person whom i choose from picker?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a mistake that is I am calling ABPeoplePickerNavigationController instead of ABPersonViewController. So that it showing whole contact list instead of particular contact.

Thanks to all to visit this question.